# Can I call my function in this example immediately instead of wrap it by anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hoverintent

I don't know how to pass $(this) in direct call

```
var parentLI = $("#nav .parent");

parentLI.hoverIntent(function() {
    showUL($(this));
}, function() {
    hideUL($(this));
});
```

Comment: It means current hover LI element, thanks,  Rory's answer is it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the functions by reference:

```
parentLI.hoverIntent(showUL, hideUL);
```

Then in those functions you can refer to the element which raised the event by the `this` keyword:

```
function showUL() {
   var $el = $(this);
   // do something with $el...
}
```